# please anyone can help to convert xml to json form textbox

Tags: c#, xml, json

hey guys please anyone help me in this code 
i'm using C# to get xml from textBox and store it in string 
i want to convert it to json when i use XmlDocument for example 
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocment();

when i use doc.loadXml(string); 
i have here error cald unhandledException 
this is my code

```
        string xml2 = XMLResult.Text;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml2);

        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);


        JSONResult.Text = JSONResult.Text + jsonText.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you know if your textbox isn't encoding your data and causing an error with invalid xml?

Comment: the xml in the textbox doesn't have any error i think the error was when i load it

Comment: I've had situations where asp.net forms is encoding the content of the textbox because it looks like HTML and when it encodes the text, it is using special characters that aren't legal in xml. Can you provide a before and after snap show of the xml you are loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code within try block and catch the exception to know what is wrong.That would be good practice.